# Windows bat file to open new window and launch script

Tags: windows, powershell, rsync

Tools : Windows 7 & powershell & Rsync

Goal  : Create a bat file to launch rsync in such a way that the output is scrolling in the new window. Once command terminates the window shall remain open for inspection.

Tried this code :

```
start powershell \k C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
```

When double click on the bat file there seems to be a short popup. But it closes and then nothing happens.

What's missing?

UPDATE:

Following works in cmd:

```
start cmd /K "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe" -av /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
```

But desire is to use powershell:

```
start powershell -NoExit "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe" -av /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
```

Throws this error:

```
The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:11
+ C:\Program <<<<  Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av /d/Images/Dia_scans  /f/Shiva_D/Images
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is proper quotation rule for powershell vs cmd when path / argument has space char?

UPDATE2:

Proposed code:

```
start powershell -NoExit Start-Process -NoNewWindow "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av --delete /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images"
```

Gives popup window with this error.

```
    Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'av'.
At line:1 char:71
+ Start-Process -NoNewWindow C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av <<<<
--delete /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

UPDATE3/CLOSING

It's easier to user cmd. I am abandoning powershell for now. Using this code in cmd works fine and is reasonably intuitive.

```
start cmd /K "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe" -av --delete /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
```

Comment: PowerShell does not use `/k`, and you have the wrong slash (backwards) anyway. See [Microsoft Docs on about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) and you might also find [SS64 on `CMD`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) of interest as well.

Comment: In short: When calling PowerShell's _CLI_ (`powershell.exe` for _Windows PowerShell_, `pwsh` for _PowerShell (Core) 7+_) from the outside, using (possibly implied) `-Command` / `-c`, you need to _escape_ `"` chars. you want passed through as part of the command: `\"` works in principle, but can break when calling from `cmd.exe`. In that case, use `"^""` (sic) with `powershell.exe`, and `""` with `pwsh.exe`, inside overall `"..."` quoting. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-noexit` rather than `/k`

For testing run your command in an already open cmd window so you'll see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [escape the spaces](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/powershell-path-with-spaces/).

For example:

```bash
start powershell -NoExit & "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe" -av /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
```

**EDIT:**

Forgot about the goal... Try to use `-NoNewWindow`

```bash
start powershell -NoExit Start-Process -NoNewWindow "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe" -av /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images
```

**EDIT2:**:

```bash
start powershell -NoExit Start-Process -NoNewWindow "C:\Program Files2\Git\usr\bin\rsync.exe" -ArgumentList '-av /d/Images/Dia_scans /f/Shiva_D/Images'
```

Comment: That solution starts two windows. One with PS interactive prompt. The other with scrolling output. First window is not desired.

Comment: @GertGottschalk See the edit, if it's still not what you desire then update me.

Comment: Proposed code starts window but throws error message about '-av' option (See above UPDATE2). Those are legal in rsync but seems got interpreted by the shell?